# InfoPath custom forms - Dynamically create controls in the form

Tags: list, infopath, custom-form, user-controls

Is it possible to dynamically (at runtime) create controls in an InfoPath form?

Some background: I have a list for which the new item is a custom form created with InfoPath. It contains some drop-downs based in it. Depending on the selected value in the drop-down I want to add more drop-downs in the form.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dynamically creating dropdowns why dont we think about hiding and unhiding dropdown controls in the form which will also reduce the complexity of creating them dynamically. Once its visible, you can use your logic to fill the data in these dropdowns.